# WSO2 API Manager with Mysql Cluster backend - NDB sql scripts

Tags: wso2

I'm setting up the WSO2 API Manager with a MySQL Cluster backend. In the /dbscripts directory within the install directory for the API Manager, there are .sql scripts for setting up the database with either the mysql.sql script, which uses InnoDB, or the mysql_cluster.sql script which uses NDB. My problem is the apimgt database, which from this article: http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Clustering+API+Manager , says to use the script in /dbscripts/apimgt/mysql.sql, but there is no equivalent script for the MySQL Cluster setup. I attempted to just replace all instances of ENGINE InnoDB with ENGINE NDB in the script, but when trying to import that into MySQL I get: ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 82: Cannot add foreign key constraint. Does anyone know of a MySQL Cluster script for this database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Manager does not provide mysql cluster script with the pack. 
For converting it to use in mysql cluster,

Yes you need to change the engine to NDB. 
Also you have to remove all the forign key constraints and indexes.

Comment: i am facing same issues with identity server all versions.. is it safe to just remove the cascade on delete and update? wouldnt it have any consequences if in the code of wso2 they are not deleting the foreign records manually?